# Vertex AI endpoint 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: python, docker, google-cloud-platform, artificial-intelligence, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I tried to deploy a custom container to Vertex AI endpoint using LLM model (PaLM), the container is successfully deployed to the endpoint with the following code and dockerfile. But when I tried to query it with Vertex AI API or gcloud cli, I get a 500 Internal Server Error reply.

May I know what's the cause of this error?

Am I using the right way to deploy the model?

Python Code

```
import uvicorn

#import tensorflow as tf
import os
import numpy as np
#from enum import Enum
#from typing import List, Optional
#from pydantic import BaseModel

from fastapi import Request, FastAPI, Response
from fastapi.responses import JSONResponse

from langchain.vectorstores.matching_engine import MatchingEngine
from langchain.agents import Tool
from langchain.embeddings import VertexAIEmbeddings
from vertexai.preview.language_models import TextGenerationModel

embeddings = VertexAIEmbeddings()

INDEX_ID = "<index id>"
ENDPOINT_ID = "<index endpoint id>"
PROJECT_ID = '<project name>'
REGION = 'us-central1'
DOCS_BUCKET='<bucket name>'
TEXT_GENERATION_MODEL='text-bison@001'

def matching_engine_search(question):

    vector_store = MatchingEngine.from_components(
                        index_id=INDEX_ID,
                        region=REGION,
                        embedding=embeddings,
                        project_id=PROJECT_ID,
                        endpoint_id=ENDPOINT_ID,
                        gcs_bucket_name=DOCS_BUCKET)

    relevant_documentation=vector_store.similarity_search(question, k=8)
    context = "\n".join([doc.page_content for doc in relevant_documentation])[:10000] #[:10000]
    return str(context)

app = FastAPI(title="Chatbot")

AIP_HEALTH_ROUTE = os.environ.get('AIP_HEALTH_ROUTE', '/health')
AIP_PREDICT_ROUTE = os.environ.get('AIP_PREDICT_ROUTE', '/predict')

#class Prediction(BaseModel):
#  response: str 


@app.get(AIP_HEALTH_ROUTE, status_code=200)
async def health():
    return {'health': 'ok'}

@app.post(AIP_PREDICT_ROUTE)#, 
          #response_model=Predictions,
          #response_model_exclude_unset=True
async def predict(request: Request):
    body = await request.json()
    print(body)

    question = body["question"]

    matching_engine_response=matching_engine_search(question)

    prompt=f"""
    Follow exactly those 3 steps:
    1. Read the context below and aggregrate this data
    Context : {matching_engine_response}
    2. Answer the question using only this context
    3. Show the source for your answers
    User Question: {question}


    If you don't have any context and are unsure of the answer, reply that you don't know about this topic.
    """

    model = TextGenerationModel.from_pretrained(TEXT_GENERATION_MODEL)
    response = model.predict(
            prompt,
            temperature=0.2,
            top_k=40,
            top_p=.8,
            max_output_tokens=1024,
    )

    print(f"Question: \n{question}")
    print(f"Response: \n{response.text}")


    outputs = response.text

    return {"predictions": [{"response": response.text}] }#Prediction(outputs)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0",port=8080)
```

Docker file

```
FROM tiangolo/uvicorn-gunicorn-fastapi:python3.8-slim
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir google-cloud-aiplatform==1.25.0 langchain==0.0.187 xmltodict==0.13.0 unstructured==0.7.0 pdf2image==1.16.3 numpy==1.23.1 pydantic==1.10.8 typing-inspect==0.8.0 typing_extensions==4.5.0
COPY main.py ./main.py
```

Cloudbuild.yaml

```
steps:
# Build the container image
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: ['build', '-t', 'gcr.io/<project name>/chatbot', '.']
# Push the container image to Container Registry
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: ['push', 'gcr.io/<project name>/chatbot']

images:
- gcr.io/<project name>/chatbot
```

Code to query the model endpoint

```
from google.cloud import aiplatform

aiplatform.init(project=PROJECT_ID,
                location=REGION)

instances = [{"question": "<Some question>"}]

endpoint = aiplatform.Endpoint("projects/<project id>/locations/us-central1/endpoints/<model endpoint id>")

prediction = endpoint.predict(instances=instances)
print(prediction)
```

Error message

[image]

Comment: Hi @user1758952, Are you facing this error for the first time ? Usually, the internal errors are transient and trying to resend the request might resolve the issue.<br>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the [document](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/general/troubleshooting?hl=en#vertex-ai-vizier), the internal errors are usually transient and trying to resend the request might resolve the issue. If the error still persists, you can [contact support](https://cloud.google.com/support) or you can open a new thread on the [issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) describing your issue.